# aggrid angular8 select drop down in column

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I am implementing aggrid enterprise version in my angular 8 project.
I am having the following requirement:

1)I need a select drop down in aggrid columns so that user can select the value from drop down and once we select a new value from drop down we should fetch the corresponding id instead of the label.

for example:
I have a vendor cell in agrid which we want to display select drop down.
From API I am getting the following rows for vendor:

```
vendor = [{
"id": 1,
"name": "Test_Vendor"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Test_Vendor5"
}
]
```

In the grid column for vendor we should show the vendor name as select drop down.If user select a different vendor name we should fetch the 'id' of cell instead of vendor name.

Answer (score 1):

In [this link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/) there is an example to add a button in the row, You can use this to add a selectBox to the grid. You have to change the `frameworkComponents` and `cellRenderer` in the `columnDefs`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.